# IO::Compress::Zip read from filehandle into buffer

Tags: perl, io, compression, zip, cpan

I'm trying to build a zipped xml-file on the fly and send it to the browser. I'm using [`IO::Compress::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aCompress%3a%3aZip) with [`IO::String`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aString) for that, but it doesn't work as I would expect from the documentation.

First my code:

```
my $zipped_file;
foreach (@{$par{directory}}) {
    my $input = IO::String->new($_->[0]);
    zip $input => \$zipped_file, Append => 1, BinModeIn => 1|0; # Tried both for BinModeIn
}
return $zipped_file;
```

`$par{directory}` is an arrayref with the following structure:

```
[
    ['DATA', 'FILENAME'], ['DATA', 'FILENAME'], ...
]
```

The data in `$par{directory}` is a string like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<derivatives>
     <derivative ag="111520420" vhash="d6712f201155a9afb64dc5a5ba369c99">
        //Some data
    </derivative>
</derivatives>
```

All I get, when I try to download the file as a .zip-archive with one empty file. Any hints on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is bizarre. I've now tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Compress::Zip 'zip';

my $xml1 = <<END_XML;
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <derivatives>
        <derivative ag="111520420" vhash="d6712f201155a9afb64dc5a5ba369c99">
            //Some data
        </derivative>
    </derivatives>
END_XML  

my $xml2 = <<END_XML;
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <derivatives2>
         <derivative2 ag="111520420" vhash="d6712f201155a9afb64dc5a5ba369c99">
             //Some data
         </derivative2>
     </derivatives2>
END_XML  

my $files = [[$xml1, 'xml1'], [$xml2, 'xml2']];
my $zipped_file;

foreach (@$files) {
    open my $input, '<', \$_->[0];
    zip $input => \$zipped_file, Append => 1, BinModeIn => 1;
}

open my $fh, '>:raw', 'zip.zip';
print $fh $zipped_file;
close $fh;
```

The archive is still empty.

Comment: try changing the zip line to this `zip $input => \$zipped_file, Append => 1, Name => $_->[1], BinModeIn => 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***Append*** option for zip isn't doing what you expect. It doesn't update the existing zip file. It creates a new one & appends it to the file/buffer you supply. In your case you will end up with a series of zip containers back-to-back.

Here's a way to achieve what you want with Archive::Zip::SimpleZip - this is just a wrapper around IO::Compress::Zip written to handle this type of use-case.

```
use Archive::Zip::SimpleZip ;

my $zipped_file;
my $zip = new Archive::Zip::SimpleZip \$zipped_file ;
foreach (@{$par{directory}}) {
  $zip->addString($_->[0], Name => $_->[1]);
}
$zip->close();
return $zipped_file;
```

Comment: That works :-D
Is there something similar to `Archive::Zip::SimpleZip` for `IO::Compress::Gzip`? Because I have to use both gzip and zip.

Comment: Sorry, Archive::Zip::SimpleZip of only for Zip files.  

Your original approach should work fine if you  just replace IO::Compress::Zip with IO::Compress::Gzip, and use "gzip" instead of "zip". Some thing like this (untested)  

    gzip \$_->[0] => \$zipped_file, Append => 1, Name => $_->[1] ;  

The gzip spec (RFC 1952)allows back-to-back gzip files, so the Append option is ok in this case.  

Whether the browser can handle concatenated gzip files is another story.

Comment: Well, shouldn't my approach work though, with Append => 0 and only one file?

Comment: Yes, it will, as long as you are only writing a single gzip file/container into `$zipped_file`.  So that means you would do something like this `gzip \$par{directory}[0][0] => \$zipped_file`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is more likely to be with what you are doing with `$zipped_file` after you have created it.

The program below works for me. I have written the zipped string to a binary file, and unzipping it using a separate utility delivers the original XML.

I would prefer to abandon `IO::String` and  use the built-in `open my $input, '<', \$_->[0]` instead, but it seems to work either way.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip 'zip';
use IO::String;

my $xml = <<END_XML;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<derivatives>
     <derivative ag="111520420" vhash="d6712f201155a9afb64dc5a5ba369c99">
        //Some data
    </derivative>
</derivatives>
END_XML

my $zipped_file;

my $input = IO::String->new($xml);

zip $input => \$zipped_file, Append => 0, BinModeIn => 1;

open my $fh, '>:raw', 'zip.zip';
print $fh $zipped_file;
close $fh;
```

**Update**

By the way, it seems there's no need to open an IO stream to the input data at all: you can just pass a reference to the scalar containing the data. So the above becomes just

```
my $zipped_file;

zip \$xml => \$zipped_file, Append => 0, BinModeIn => 1;

open my $fh, '>:raw', 'zip.zip';
print $fh $zipped_file;
close $fh;
```

Comment: I've tried it that way too, but since it didn't work out for me, I tried doing it with a filehandle.

Comment: I've now copied your code into a script and it still doesn't work for me. No errors, nothing, just an empty zip-archive which i'm not able to unzip (mapname:  conversion of  failed).
Could it have something to do with the fact, that I can't pass a name for the file inside the archive?

Comment: How odd. You should check that your modules are up to date. Mine creates a file called `zip.zip` containing a single file called `zip` with the XML in it.

Comment: I have `IO::Compress::Zip` version 2.055, and it appears to create a member called `xxx` if you name the zip file `xxx.zip`.

Comment: I've upgraded `IO::Compress::Zip`, but still got the same problem.
It's version 2.060 now

Comment: OK, how about checking the length of `$zipped_file` after you've created it. I get about 200 bytes.